# 'cache is not defined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hi i'm making a discord bot with a event and command handler but in my ready.js of my events it gives an error on line 4.

ready.js:

```
module.exports = (client, discord) => {
    const config = require('../../config.json')
    const activities_list = [
        `${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`,
        `!help`,
        `${client.users.cache.size} users`
    ]
    console.log(`${client.user.username} is online!`)
    setInterval(() => {
        const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * activities_list.length - 1) + 1;
        client.user.setActivity(activities_list[i], { type: "LISTENING" })
    })
}
```

can anyone help me with fixing this?

Comment: What's the error message? Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: ```client.users``` print this with console...

Comment: Are you putting `(client, discord)` correctly, in the right order?

Comment: As @MrMythical mentioned, your `client` is not a `client`. Make sure, you're passing it correctly.

Comment: @MrMythical i put it like ```(discord, client)``` and it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `client` is not an actual Discord client. Would you show as where you are calling this function. My guess is that it would work like this:

```js
module.exports = (client, discord) => {
    const config = require('../../config.json')
    const activities_list = [
        `${discord.guilds.cache.size} servers`,
        `!help`,
        `${discord.users.cache.size} users`
    ]
    console.log(`${discord.user.username} is online!`)
    setInterval(() => {
        const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * activities_list.length);
        discord.user.setActivity(activities_list[i], { type: "LISTENING" });
    })
}
```